# Convergence (or not) of a complex series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine whether the series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln{(n)}+\sqrt{(\ln{(n)})^3}}$$ convergence or not. I’m guess that we use the comparison test here comparing the series above to $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(\ln{(n)})^3}}.$$ Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry it will be compared to $\frac{1}{n\ln{(n)}}$ which diverges by the integral test.

Comment: Your guess is correct. It indeed diverges by that reasoning.

Comment: It should be compared to $\sum\frac{1}{2nln(n)}$